# Defining attribute ID at runtime

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm creating DIVs on runtime based on user input.

```html
@foreach (var item in Model.BUM_List)
{
  <div class="shadow col-sm-2 col-xs-4">
    <input class="Columndiv" value="@item.Columns" id="" readonly/>
    <input type="checkbox"/><label id="lblSelectColumn">Include this Column</label>
  </div>
}
```

My question is, how do I define ID for each of these newly created DIVs, after creation? It can be names as `Column1`, `Column2`, etc.

I tried using the following function, but it's only useful after the DIVs have been created.

```
$("#Submit_Table").click(function () {
  var i = 0;
  $('.Columndiv').each(function () {
    i++;
    var newID = 'menu' + i;
    $(this).attr('id', newID);
    $(this).val(i);
  });
});
```

Comment: Simple solution: don't. Incremental `id` attributes are an anti-pattern which create unnecessarily complex logic. Use a common class on all the elements and target individual elements by index or by traversing the DOM when required.

Comment: If you really feel the need to do this, set the `id` and `value` in the HTML you generate server side in your razor logic.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding dynamic id by getting the value from item

```
<div class="shadow col-sm-2 col-xs-4" id="topDiv@item.code">
```

I am assuming your item will have some unique id which you can use.